# How to check status of a document with DocuSign?

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api, docusignapi

We are going to use DocuSign API to sign our documents. Once document is uploaded to get signed/declined, we have TWO ways to get the status of the document (signed or declined):

1. Checking the status of document by repeatedly calling DocuSign API from our WCF service (which is limited to 1000 calls per hour,  but we can limit it to 1 call per document per hour)
2. Sending a public URL with the envelope which will get called whenever the status of document is changed? (https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Send%20an%20Envelope.htm)
      This method requires updating a parameter called 'eventNotification' with the public URL on our environment.

I would like to know which one is better approach architecture wise? On an average we expect 50 documents a month to get signed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, best practice would be approach #2 -- i.e., configure DocuSign Connect such that it automatically sends a notification (to the endpoint you specify) each time one of the specified Envelope events occurs.  There are lots of advantages to this approach, including:

- using Connect doesn't count against your 1000 API calls per hour limit
- notifications will be sent/received in (relative) real-time
- using Connect doesn't require that you go through the "API Certification" process

The DocuSign Connect Service Guide (https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/connect-guide.pdf) describes how to configure/implement Connect.  You'll need to do a little bit of custom development to build the "listener" that will receive and parse the XML notifications from DocuSign, but this is straight-forward and sample code (in several different languages) is available on GitHub.

***Note***: If you want DocuSign to automatically send notifications for **all envelopes** (for the senders you specify), you can just configure Connect at the Account-level via the DocuSign web console (**Preferences >> Connect**), rather than having to specify **eventNotification** as part of each **Create Envelope** API request.  If you use this approach, then any future configuration changes can be made simply via the DocuSign web console (**Preferences >> Connect**), rather than having to make code changes. i.e., if you want to add notifications for other events, include or exclude the document(s) themselves, etc.